# JQuery: Change class when radiobutton is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need some help with javascript.

Here is the link to the code in JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Gopher69/B98kZ/4/

My JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//add the Selected class to the checked radio button
$('[type=radio]').parent().addClass("selected");
//If another radio button is clicked, add the select class, and remove it from the       previously selected radio
$('input').click(function() {
    $('input:not(:checked)').parent().removeClass("radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option").find("class").html("radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option");
    $('input:checked').parent().addClass("radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option").find("class").html("radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option active");
});});
```

I want to adjust the the background color for the radio buttons just like I did with the hover effect with css. So I need to add something like "checked" to the class when the radiobutton is active.

I found this post but I'm juts not getting foreword: [jQuery Checkbox selection and change class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672538/jquery-checkbox-selection-and-change-class)

If somebody could help me out, I would be very thankfull.

Comment: When you use `find("class")`, you should use a CSS selector instead of just the class name. In your case, that would be `.find(".class")` if you want to find all elements with the CSS class 'class'.

Answer (score 3):

you can use pure css to do this:

```
  input[type="radio"]:checked {
    /* put some style here */
  }
```

Comment: @roXon sadly, not. by the way, i ever saw a news that says that hquery 2.0 will not support old versions of IE anymore

Comment: -1 For no cross browser compatibility (IE7 still is a widely used browser).

Comment: @gamehelp16 yes, but 1.9 will be sometimes updated with new features fixes. You can always keep 1.9 till IE 7,8 die or create a condition in your `<head>` to toggle versions (if really needed)

Comment: @Robin: sure? i think more people uses IE8 and newer

Comment: jQuery 1.9 and 2.0 will be updated side-by-side as much as possible. 2.0 gives developers a smaller file and can include features targeting latest browsers without having to worry about legacy compatibility. IE has been changed drastically and IE10 and future will be so much more in sync with what other browsers support. See [jQuery Core: Version 1.9 and beyond](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/) and [jQuery 1.9 and 2.0 — TL;DR Edition](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/07/01/jquery-1-9-and-2-0-tldr-edition/) for more details

Comment: @gamehelp16 I didn't say that IE7 is bigger than IE8 or other IE versions but despite the fact that Google, jQuery and others drop support for IE7, it still is a browser that your visitors will use and therefore you should test for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#" + radioelementid).on("change",function(){  
$(this).addClass("testClass")   
//or   
$(this).removeClass("testClass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Krunal Goswami's answer - even shorter:

```
$("#" + elementId).on("change",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("checked");
});
```

### Note

That should do your trick. Although I don't recommend using this. Instead try a 'custom checkbox' implementation / jQuery plugin since native browser checkboxes don't really like being styled (cross browser).